# MongoDB - findAndModify vs findOne Performance

Tags: mongodb

Is findAndModify query slower than findOne . Suppose to one collection documents are being inserted suppose 100- 200 documents per 2 seconds . Which is faster doing a findOne or findAndModify . Assume the collection is indexed properly and my query makes use of the index

Comment: You do realize that both have different functions. Unless you clearly show your intent this is not likely to be a popular question. People are not liking it as I am typing.

Comment: Hi , findAndModify is different from findOne with respect to the atomic update  factor of the former . My intent here is which query would be faster to retrieve the documents from that collection . I can do a findAndModify and set a processed flag to in progress . Wherein i can also do a findOne sort by ObjectId and use the current objectId as a reference to retrieve the subsequent documents thereby not using a findAndModify . Which one do you suggest

Comment: To make clear the collection is not queried from multiple threads . So i can do away with findAndModify . But am seeing findAndModify performs slowly than findOne . The query criteria being the same making use of a compund index . Whats the reason behind this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noted, `.findAndModify()` is intended to do exactly what it says and "modify" the document that is retrieved, either by update or removal. The atomic nature exists to avoid concurrency state problems, where if your `.findOne()` on a document, then make changes to the content and then try to `.update()` for example.

In that latter usage case there is "no guarantee" that the document is the same as what was there when your "retrieved" it via `.findOne()`. So in fact you could possibly be overwriting changes that were made by another process.

As for performance, this is the classic comparing "apples to oranges" as they are two different things. One just returns the single first result from a cursor in the case of `.findOne()` and the other in `.findAndModify()` grabs possibly the orginal document, makes changes with the default write concern or other specified write concern, then either returns or retrieves the document before relinquishing any control for others to modify.

There are varying levels of "locking" per version of MongoDB, but the point is that a `.findAndModify()` is designed to do more work, so it naturally takes longer.

If you can live with just retrieving a document and then sending an update then fine. Be aware that the "apples to apples" you should be comparing is **both** of those operations and how that performs.

It also may be that you can look into setting the write concern for these operations as you may also be able to live with the fact that writes are not acknowleded. But it is up to you really. But in most peoples opinion it's generally better to use the tools that are optimized to their purpose.

Comment: Indeed it is like comparing apples to oranges, +1

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the answers , I debugged more into the issue and it seems like there are lots of writes happening into the database which i guess is slowing down the find queries . I read somewhere that write locks are exclusive per mongod instance . and the locks are writer greedy  . So that would mean if inserts are happening at the rate of 1000 doc/second into the db ,the find queries would block quite often and hence the slowness , eventhough the writes are into one collection and reads are done on some other collection within the same mongod instance . Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: @redeemed Not too sure what this has to do with your original question. The two methods you are looking at are completely different things, so that is your answer. You seem to be straying into DBA rather than developer territory here and would therefore be better of posting a specific question on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks neil , i have posted this in dba stackexchange . Whole thing is new to me , apologize for inconveniences caused . Thanks